# Batches of different sized inputs (with fully convolutional nets)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

A strength of [Fully Convolutional Neural Nets](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) is that they naturally accept inputs of any size, and are capable of producing outputs of any size. This is great for pixel-wise prediction and segmentation tasks.

But what happens with training batches? To construct a minibatch you must know the size of your inputs in advance. How are you supposed to construct a minibatch of various sized inputs?

Currently, I can only work out how to have a `batch size = 1`. Which jumps around too much to ever converge, in my experiments.

I considered using some kind of zero padding to make all inputs the size of the largest in the training set, but then I need to create an artificial "padding" target category, because every pixel needs something to map to. Less than ideal. Furthermore it biases my model evaluation because the net is very good at classifying "padding" space (which is not meaningful data).

The best idea I can think of is to group training images into similar-sized batches, so that they never have "way too much" padding. Perhaps?

Is there something that can be done with masking to accomplish this task? I know that the `keras.layers.core.Masking` is not supported in convolutional nets...

Here's my Keras model:

```
def build_net():
    # apply a convolution 1d of length 7 to a sequence with NUM_FEATURES channels
    # with 32 output feature maps
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(32, 7, border_mode='same', input_shape=(None, NUM_FEATURES)))

    # apply a 1x1x3 convolution to collapse down to NUM_CATEGORIES feature maps
    model.add(Convolution1D(NUM_CATEGORIES, 1, border_mode='same'))

    # pass through softmax classifier
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08), metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Comment: Batch size of 1 is not online learning, its just SGD.